# Deserializing a string into a struct with 2 uint fields

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON document containing data about all American presidents. Here is an example:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "George Washington",
    "years": "1789-1797"
}
```

I have defined a class `President` as follows:

```
public class President
{
    [JsonProperty("id")] public int Id;
    [JsonProperty("name")] public string Name;
    [JsonProperty("years")] public Reign Reign;
}
```

And here is my `Reign` struct:

```
public struct Reign
{
    public uint StartYear;
    public uint EndYear;
}
```

I would like to deserialise the JSON document into a `President[]`. Deserialising the `Id` and `Name` fields are straightforward; but if I want to deserialise the string `1789-1797` into an instance of `Reign` where `StartYear` is `1789` and `EndYear` is `1797`, how should I go about achieving it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = "{ \"id\": 1, \"name\": \"George Washington\", \"years\": \"1789-1797\" }";
        President president = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<President>(json);
    }
}

public class President
{
    [JsonProperty("id")] public int Id;
    [JsonProperty("name")] public string Name;
    [JsonProperty("years")] private string _reign
    {
        set
        {
            string[] years = value.Split('-');
            Reign = new Reign
            {
                StartYear = uint.Parse(years[0]),
                EndYear = uint.Parse(years[1])
            };
        }
    }
    public Reign Reign;
}

public struct Reign
{
    public uint StartYear;
    public uint EndYear;
}
```